# Rescaling Decimal128 value would cause data loss

Tags: pandas, dataframe, parquet, pyarrow

I have a dataframe that I want to convert to parquet file with pyarrow schema

The piece of code that does that looks like this

```
df = DataFrame({
    "BOOKG_AMT_XCHG_RATE_NMRC": [79812042284098215031627424085742912847.808901592419987254]
})
df[['BOOKG_AMT_XCHG_RATE_NMRC']] = df[['BOOKG_AMT_XCHG_RATE_NMRC']].applymap(str).applymap(Decimal)
df.to_parquet(parquet_file, schema=pa.schema([('BOOKG_AMT_XCHG_RATE_NMRC', pa.decimal128(38, 18))]))
```

When I run it I get this error

```
('Rescaling Decimal128 value would cause data loss', 'Conversion failed for column BOOKG_AMT_XCHG_RATE_NMRC with type object')
```

What is the problem? Both left and right digits (38, 18) looks fine in the decimal value. And it fails in `to_parquet` function

If I change to `decimal256` it fails with error

```
Decimal type with precision 38 does not fit into precision inferred from first array element: 38
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your number has got 56 digits (38 + 18), so you should use a `pa.decimal256(56, 18)` (56 digits, 18 of them after the `,`). You can't use pa.decimal128 for your number, because your number has more than 38 digits.

```py
import pandas as pd
from decimal import Decimal
import pyarrow as pa

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "BOOKG_AMT_XCHG_RATE_NMRC": ["79812042284098215031627424085742912847.808901592419987254"]
})
df[['BOOKG_AMT_XCHG_RATE_NMRC']] = df[['BOOKG_AMT_XCHG_RATE_NMRC']].applymap(str).applymap(Decimal)
df.to_parquet('foo.parquet', schema=pa.schema([('BOOKG_AMT_XCHG_RATE_NMRC', pa.decimal256(56, 18))]))
```