unable to upload pandas dataFrame in bigQuery
For some reason, I'm unable to use pandas function pandas.DataFrame.to_gbq (here).
I've been building this small example to reproduce the issue :
table_schema = [{'name':'company','type':'STRING'},
    {'name':'country','type':'STRING'},
    {'name':'revenue','type':'NUMERIC'},
    {'name':'pageviews','type':'INTEGER'}]
dataframe = pandas.DataFrame({
    'company': ['stackoverflow'],
    'country': ['france'],
    'revenue': [1000.23],
    'pageviews': [10000]})

table_name = 'my_dataset.petit_test'

dataframe.to_gbq(table_name,
      'PROJECT_ID',
      chunksize=100000,
      if_exists='replace',
      table_schema=table_schema)

As a result, I get a big error message ending as follow:
pandas_gbq.exceptions.ConversionError: Could not convert DataFrame to Parquet.

I can't figure out what is going wrong here.
Does anyone get the understanding ?

As a comment, I'm adding a previous line interesting in the error message that can lead to maybe an explanation: pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: Rescaling Decimal128 value would cause data loss. It I check another question related to that error, I see that it might be because a number is too big (here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75698202/rescaling-decimal128-value-would-cause-data-loss) but it makes no sense here where the number is quite short.

Hi @JCDB, Did you check this stack link, for similar error ? Let me know if this helps you or not.

HI @DhirajSingh, I've been taking a look but this does not help? I tried on a new table (let's say petit_test_2) and still have the bug... Thank you anyway :)

It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker describing your issue.

It seems the issue may be related to the data type of the 'revenue' field. In BigQuery, there isn't a 'NUMERIC' type directly available. To resolve this, I recommend defining the 'revenue' field as type 'FLOAT' instead.

Nope. NUMERIC type exists indeed, and I've been also trying with data types FLOAC64 and DECIMAL without more success: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types

For some reason, it started working after I deleted the test table, update the pandas library in my Python and tested again.
The issue remains myterious to me but seems to have fixed itself :)
